# Modifying JSON by using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to modify a JSON file by using the Linux command line.

I tried these steps:

```
[root@localhost]# INPUT="dsa"
[root@localhost]# echo $INPUT
dsa
[root@localhost]# CONF_FILE=test.json
[root@localhost]# echo $CONF_FILE
test.json
[root@localhost]# cat $CONF_FILE
{
  "global" : {
    "name" : "asd",
    "id" : 1
  }
}
[root@localhost]# jq -r '.global.name |= '""$INPUT"" $CONF_FILE > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json $CONF_FILE
jq: error: dsa/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.global.name |= dsa
jq: 1 compile error
```

Desired output:

```
[root@localhost]# cat $CONF_FILE
    {   "global" : {
    "name" : "dsa",
    "id" : 1   } }
```

Comment: a little tip, don't login as root to do work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only problem was that the script passed to `jq` was quoted incorrectly.

In your particular case, using a single double-quoted string with embedded `\`-escaped `"` instances is probably simplest:

```
jq -r ".global.name = \"$INPUT\"" "$CONF_FILE" > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json "$CONF_FILE"
```

Generally, however, **[chepner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41505474/45375) shows a more robust alternative to embedding the shell variable reference directly in the script**: Using the **`--arg` option** to pass a value as a `jq` *variable* allows *single-quoting* the script, which is preferable, because it avoids confusion over what elements are expanded by the shell up front and obviates the need for escaping `$` instances that should be passed through to `jq`.

Also:

- Just `=` is sufficient to assign the value; while `|=`, the so-called update operator, works too, it behaves the same as `=` in this instance, because the RHS is a *literal*, not an expression referencing the LHS - see [the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment).
- You should routinely double-quote your shell-variable references and you should avoid use of all-uppercase variable names in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

---

As for **why your quoting didn't work**:

`'.global.name |= '""$INPUT""` is composed of the following tokens:

- String literal `.global.name |=` (due to single-quoting)
- String literal `""` - i.e., the empty string - the quotes will be *removed* by the shell before `jq` sees the script
- An *unquoted* reference to variable `$INPUT` (which makes its value subject to word-splitting and globbing).
- Another instance of literal `""`.

With your sample value, `jq` ended up seeing the following string as its script:

```
.global.name |= dsa
```

As you can see, the double quotes are missing, causing `jq` to interpret `dsa` as a *function name* rather than a string literal, and since no argument was passed to (non-existent) function `dsa`, `jq`'s error message referenced it as `dsa/0` - a function with no (`0`) arguments.

Answer (score 5):

It's much simpler and safer to pass the value using the `--arg` option:

```
jq -r --arg newname "$INPUT" '.global.name |= $newname' "$CONF_FILE"
```

This ensures that the exact value of `$INPUT` is used and quoted as a JSON value.

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq` with a straight forward filter, should do it for you.

```
.global.name = "dsa"
```

i.e.

```
jq '.global.name = "dsa"' json-file
{
  "global": {
    "name": "dsa",
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

You can play around with your json-filters, [here](https://jqplay.org/).

Comment: `|=` wasn't the problem; the quoting was.

Comment: @chepner: didn't catch it earlier.

Comment: Also note that _filter_ is a very broad concept in `jq` (to quote from the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/): 'A jq program is a “filter”: it takes an input, and produces an output.'), whereas the feature of interest here is an _assignment_.